# Extract Parts of a Function

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have an expression of the form

```
a Integrate[b[t], {t, 0, x}]
```

and I would like to take the coefficient $a$, save it to a list, take the $b(t)$ out of the integral, and save it to a different list. $b(t)$ could be

```
Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (-t + x)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -3 t^2]
```

The idea is that *Mathematica* can't do the integration because of the complexity of $b(t)$, but there's a trick that has to be implemented manually on $b(t)$ and then it works.

To extract the coefficient I understand I have to use some sort of `Coefficient` or `CoefficientList` except we don't have a power anymore. To extract out $b(t)$ I understand `First@Integrate[b[t], {t, 0, x}]` would work but I think the coefficient in front messes it up.

I'm not really good with patterns and I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
exp = a Integrate[b[t], {t, 0, x}]
```

`a` and `b` can be extracted by

```
exp[[1]]
(* a *)
exp[[2, 1]]
(* b[t] *)
```

Note: Use `AppendTo` to add either result to a preexisting list.

**Addendum**

In answer to a comment below, suppose,

```
exp = 3 5 a e Integrate[7 b[t] g[t], {t, 0, x}];
```

If you do not mind the 3 and 5 multiplied together, then

```
Cases[exp, Except[_Integrate], {1}]
(* {15, a, e} *)
```

If you do mind, then use

```
deferexp = Defer[3 5 a e Integrate[7 b[t] g[t], {t, 0, x}]];
Cases[deferexp, Except[_Integrate] , {2}]
(* {3, 5, a, e} *)
```

Note that `FullForm` and `TreeForm` can be useful in determining where particular terms are in an expression, although the output can be voluminous.

Comment: Thanks @bbgodfrey! If, by chance, you had another constant out front `c`, then is there a way to lump all constants together so calling `exp[[1]]` would give `a c`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Extract[HoldForm[
  a Integrate[
    Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (-t + x)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 
       1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -3 t^2], {t, 0, x}]], {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}]
```

Use `HoldForm` to block evaluation and use `Extract` to take out the part you want.